# Opening PDF from a POST in a new tab

Tags: javascript, pdf, xmlhttprequest, fileapi, content-disposition

#### What I need to do :

I need to open the file in a **new tab in Firefox**(other browser support isn't important)

That **filename** needs to match the Content-Disposition.

So I send data in my **POST** to a server, then I receive a **PDF file** in response.
The headers of the response are (an example):

```
Content-Type: application/pdf 
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Disposition
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file name.pdf" 
Content-Length: 234
```

My response is the PDF file itself.(Blob --> application/pdf)

Also it's possible to have **multiple request at the same time**

#### What is done :

Now the file is open in a new window, but with the wrong file name(filename isn't use). Also it's block by Firefox.

My code(not all of it, only the important part):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 201){
                        var filename = this.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition').split('=')[1];
                        filename = filename.substr(1, filename.length-2);

                        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
                        window.open(url);
                    }
                };
                xhr.open('POST', host + this.getLink('preview', this.collection.jsonSchemaSwapData).href);

                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
                xhr.responseType = 'blob';
                xhr.send(JSON.stringify(this.toJSON()));
```

#### The problems :

- The browser block the new tab as a Popup(*a element*, then click on it is also blocked)
- CreateObjectURL doesn't work with file name
- Can't see the pdf in the page, because we can open a few a the same time

### How can I open the PDF with the right name in a new tab?

Comment: Do you have adBlock on?